# Is it possible to have a SQL table within an SQL table? (for dynamically generated forms)

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design, normalization

I have a form that dynamically generates elements in groups, so I cannot be sure how many things I'm going to submit to the database everytime someone submits a form.

```
Form
  -name
  -age
  -incident (0)
  -incident description (0)
  -incident (1)
  -incident description (1)
  -incident (2....)
  -incident descritpion (2....)
```

and there are about 10 possible dynamically generated form element groups, so I was thinking I would make one table for the entire form, and one table each for the dynamically generated element groups in order.

```
formdata
name varchar(30)
age int(2)
incident0 sql
incdient1 sql
```

is that possible?
or is there a different way besides creating a whole bunch of columns in my table that i rarely use?
and if i create a whole bunch of columns would there be memory waste or would it not make a difference if theres not a lot of data submitted in those columns?

Comment: By database, do you mean table?

Comment: By database do you mean table, and what dbms do you use? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle?

Comment: Yes I mean table sorry, and I use MySQL.

Comment: Yes you can add as many tables you want in a MySQL database.

Comment: I meant have tables, inside my tables. I want to know if theres a way to do that

Comment: The answer is to find a logic data structure that can express form fields in normal tables. Not tables within tables.

Comment: Tables that have tables within them **are** "normal" tables.  The stance that such tables are not "normalized" has been deprecated/obsoleted/abandoned for, well, longer than I know the relational model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer you seek is called **schema normalization**, and it is the quintessential feature of *relational* database management systems. The Particular concept is called a "one-to-many" relationship, where you have one "form" related to many incidents. This is accomplished by having one table just for incidents, and one of the columns in that table is a numeric reference to an id column in your forms table, thus each incident "knows" which form it *belongs to*.

```
FORMS
=======
id
name
age

INCIDENTS
============
id
form_id
descrition
```

Then the SQL can optionally use a *join* clause when selecting:

```
SELECT forms.name, incidents.description
FROM incidents
JOIN FORMS ON (incidents.form_id = forms.id)
```

Comment: Ah.. This seems like the way to do it.. I'll research mroe on schema normalization then, thank you.

Comment: You are quite welcome. You were right to be queezy about unused columns. That is one of the rules-of-thumb of normalization. Every column in your schema should be used for exactly one meaningful piece of information (not zero and not more than one). There are severl "levels" of normalization... welcome to one of my favorite journeys in development!

Answer (score 2):

What if one day you do not want to have 10 incidents but 20, will you change all your code? You should create the tables in a normalized way. So you create two tables.

First Table: Form (Form_id, Name, Age)

Second Table: Incident (Incident_Id, Form_Id, Description)

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL has ROW types and MULTISET types.

A MULTISET is in almost all of its aspects similar/identical to a TABLE, though they are not exactly the same thing.

So yes, standard SQL supports the concept of tables that consist of rows in which there is a column (or more) whose values are themselves MULTISETs.

Don't ask me which of the available SQL products effectively support it (*), or how to interact with such columns in any given specimen of ORM engine out there.

(*) The answer might well be "none at all".  A system that supports this feature should reasonably be expected to also support the UNNEST operator (and its opposite-direction counterpart the name of which got stuck somewhere between my brain and my keyboard), but even an engine like DB2 doesn't seem to support it.